# Example of using Anxious or nervous

Tags: american-english

Anxious means 'very eager' or feeling nervous . Can you please explain the difference via an example.
I'm interested to hear other people's opinions on this.

Comment: Asking for opinions is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nervous generally implies expectation of a negative result, while anxious can be used for any sort of anticipation, whether positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

I spent an anxious night waiting for the blood test result.  (nervous)

I am anxious to see the new James Bond movie.  (eager)

Answer (score 0):

When you experience stress, your body releases adrenalin and cortisol, so you'll have the energy for "fight or flight" as may be appropriate.

If your body releases an excess of adrenalin, you experience anxiety.

If you want to think of anxiety as "nervousness on steroids", well, cortisol IS a steroid...